# Creating a tar.gz archive of multiple directories of different locations -- "tar: Cowardly refusing to create an empty archive"

Tags: linux, command-line, tar, gzip, archive

I'm trying to create an achive:

```
$ cd /tmp
$ tar -czf test1.tar.gz -C ~/Downloads/dir1 -C ~/Documents/dir2 -C ~/dir3/dir4/dir5
```

... which is supposed not to preserve the full path of the directories in it, hence `-C`

Result

```
tar: Cowardly refusing to create an empty archive
Try 'tar --help' or 'tar --usage' for more information.
```

Why? How to fix it?

Comment: Are you meaning to archive `dir1`, `dir2` and `dir3` from those different directories? Your current command lacks the actual pathnames to archive, it only contains instructions to change to certain other directories (`-C pathname`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your command is conceptually equivalent to this:

```
tar -czf test1.tar.gz -C ~/Downloads/dir1 "" -C ~/Documents/dir2 "" -C ~/dir3/dir4/dir5 ""
```

In human terms:

- `tar -czf test1.tar.gz`: "Make a gzipped tar archive named `test1.tar.gz` to the current working directory, as follows:..."
- `-C ~/Downloads/dir1 ""`: "...First, switch to directory `~/Downloads/dir1`, and archive nothing from there..."
- `-C ~/Documents/dir2 ""`: "...then, switch to directory `~/Documents/dir2` and archive nothing from there..."
- `-C ~/dir3/dir4/dir5 ""`: "...and finally, switch to `~/dir3/dir4/dir5` and also archive nothing from there."

You probably want something like this instead:

```
tar -czf test1.tar.gz -C ~/Downloads/dir1 . -C ~/Documents/dir2 . -C ~/dir3/dir4/dir5 .
```

This replaces the "archive nothing" part with "archive the contents of the current directory", which has just been switched to using the `-C` option.

Note that when you extract the resulting archive, the archived contents of `dir1`, `dir2` and `dir5` will all be extracted to whatever is the current directory when extracting. If that's what you want, it's well and good, but it is a slightly unusual use case. (Such an archive is known as a *tar bomb* and generally disliked when encountered unexpectedly, as it won't neatly extract into a single directory created by the extraction process.)

For the sake of explanation, here is a slightly different command:

```
tar -czf test2.tar.gz -C ~/Downloads dir1 -C ~/Documents dir2 -C ~/dir3/dir4 dir5
```

When `test2.tar.gz` is extracted, it will result in:

```
./dir1
./dir2
./dir5
```

... and their contents.

Comment: re. "conceptually equivalent..." -- ngh, well yeah, except that in general the empty string is a valid argument to a command, and a different thing from not passing an  argument. It's just an invalid filename, and so will provoke errors (which the command without filenames doesn't).

Comment: Yes, I second-guessed myself whether to use  `<nothing here>` vs `""`. What is the most immediately understandable way to emphasise nothingness?

Answer (score 2):

You are not providing the file arguments for `tar` to process.

If you had provided a file argument that doesn't exist or even the empty string, `tar` would print `no such file or directory` and exit. For missing arguments, it prints that error.

---

Probably you have been confused and thought that `-C` is defining input files. It doesn't. `-C` only changes directory and the order of `-C` directives matters:

```
-C, --directory=DIR
    Change to DIR before performing any operations. This option is 
    order-sensitive, i.e.  it  affects  all options that follow.
```

It is used to get relative paths into the archive for the file arguments after any `-C` directive.

Probably you just meant to:

```
tar -czf test1.tar.gz ~/Downloads/dir1 ~/Documents/dir2 ~/dir3/dir4/dir5
```

Answer (score 1):

IMHO it is not good idea to provide absolute (in some degree) paths of archived files. Will be much better to use command:

```
tar -czf /tmp/test1.tar.gz Downloads/dir1 Documents/dir2 dir3/dir4/dir5
```

later when you extract the files this will create subdirectories in your **current** directory, not in your **home** directory